# Decode Base64 using a column as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

I would like to Decode a Base64 column from a table using the `OPENJSON` function and extract the 'a' key from that decoded string as such:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = 'column name' -- Here i am puting 'column name' because im not sure how to insert a column into a declared variable.


SELECT [Value]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
WHERE [key] = 'a';
```

**Situation:**

I have a column ('ProductsBase64') that is Base64 encoded that I would like to decode.

**Example of a unique string:**
I would like to decode an entire column however

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
where type = 2
```

Results:

```
key value   type
a   1   2
b   2   2
c   3   2
d   4   2
```

Comment: Bit confused here. `'column name'` isn't valid JSON, not is it an encoded string. I feel like we're missing some steps here.

Comment: i've clarified my question @Larnu

Comment: It's still not clear, What does base 64 decoding have to do with the JSON sample?

Comment: @MartinSmith When decoding the base64 string, the value appears as a json string with key value pairs

Comment: Right I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the original text encoding is compatible with `varchar` you can use the below (uses XML [`xs:base64Binary`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary) method to do the base 64 decoding, that is then cast to `VARCHAR` and finally passed as input to `OPENJSON`)

```
CREATE TABLE #t
  (
     ProductsBase64 VARCHAR(max)
  )

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES      ('eyJhIjoxLCJiIjoyLCJjIjozLCJkIjo0fQ=='); /*{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4} */

SELECT ca.*
FROM   #t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   OPENJSON(
                                     CONVERT (
                                               VARCHAR(MAX), 
                                               CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("ProductsBase64"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')
                                             )
                                    )
                    WHERE  type = 2) ca
```